# A pagestyle with note taking area on the verso page

Tags: header-footer, double-sided

Is there a way to create a pagestyle wich forces all of the content of a document to the recto pages and show a "note taking area" on the verso pages?

[image]

Comment: An idea: write your document as "normal", forgetting about the notes page. Compile it, and then use another "driver" document which use `\includegraphics` to insert the pages of the main document at recto pages, and the notes page at verso pages. If you are interested in this kind of solution, I can write a suitable "driver" document. Be warned however: you will lost all internal hyperlinks, and if you use \pageref, then your "main" document has to be tweaked to increase the page numbers by 2 (or perhaps you can number only recto pages)

Comment: @JLDiaz There has to be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using flowfram.sty and a combination of flowframes and staticframes. This is just to give you an idea of what might be possible:

[image: Two page spread, notes on verso, text on recto]

**The Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\width{9}
\def\height{15}

\newflowframe[odd]{3.5in}{6.5in}{0in}{0.0in}[flowtext]
\newstaticframe[even]{3.5in}{7.5in}{0in}{0.0in}[notes]

\begin{staticcontents*}{notes}
\vspace*{0.4in}
\noindent\textbf{Notes:}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
\draw[step=1mm, line width=0.1mm, black!30!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\height);
\draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!40!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\height);
\draw[step=5cm, line width=0.5mm, black!50!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\height);
\draw[step=1cm, line width=0.3mm, black!90!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\height);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{staticcontents*}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}\clearpage

\lipsum[1-25]

\end{document}
```

I edited this to provide something a little closer to what the OP wanted. I used graph paper for notes, as I am more likely to want that: The point is that virtually **anything** can go into a static box. Further, static frames are efficient: The material is typeset only once, and then reused as needed. The graph paper comes from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph-paper/. Also, `\mbox{}\clearpage` is a better way to create the blank first page.

There are some limitations and you will have to read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. I never worked with the flowfram package, but at least it seems to be of interest for me.

Comment: Works fine. There seem to be a problem with longtable: the table stops after a pagebreak (if in newflowframe).

Comment: Yes, `longtable.sty` seems to be a problem. However, I did a quick test of `supertabular.sty` and it _seems_ to work without a problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is an implementation of the idea I gave previously in a comment:

[image]
[image]

## The code

You need two pdf files. One contains the original document. The other contains a single page with the layout for the notes. In the above example, the "original" document I used was `pgfmanual.pdf`, and the layout for the notes was the file `noteslayout.pdf`,obtained by compiling the following tex source:

```
% Design of the layout for the page of notes
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}\parskip=1em
\noindent\textbf{Notes: }
\foreach \i in {1,...,31} {\hrulefill\par\noindent}
\end{document}
```

Once you have both pdfs, the following code is the "main driver" which merges the two as required:

```
% Driver to create a pdf which shows in each verso page
% a "notes" page (taken from \notelayout), and in 
% each recto page a different page (taken from \maindocument)
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\notelayout{notelayout.pdf}
\def\maindocument{pgfmanual.pdf}

\begin{document}
% Compute the number of pages of \maindocument
\pdfximage{\maindocument}
\edef\maxpag{\the\pdflastximagepages}

% Main loop
\foreach \pag in {1,...,\maxpag}
{
  \includepdf[pages=\pag]{\maindocument}
  \includepdf[pages=1]{\notelayout}
} 
\end{document}
```

Note that I removed page numbering in the notes page, which allowed me to retain the original page numbering of the main document, and thus all indexes, references to pages, etc. are correct. However, the hyperlinks are lost (not clickable).

Comment: Pretty nice. But is there a way around hardcoding the 31 in the `\foreach`? One solution could be to divide the text height by `\baselineskip` and round it in order to compute the number of iterations needed...

Comment: @Jubobs Well `<hack>` you can put any big number `</hack>`, that would generate several pages, instead of a single page, but since the driver uses only the first one... :-)

Comment: Ok. Upvote for you, Sir!

Comment: Thanks for your effort and the hints JLDiaz. I will come back to the hand work, if the flowfram solution won't work for me.