# Notes and page bibliography on verso pages

Tags: biblatex, double-sided, notes, fixme

I thought this would sound crazy, but there have been similar questions already:

- [Placing text and footnotes on separate pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36486/placing-text-and-footnotes-on-separate-pages)
- [A pagestyle with note taking area on the verso page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101413/a-pagestyle-with-note-taking-area-on-the-verso-page)
- [Figures on left pages, text on right ones with class book, numbering only on right pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig)

I’m producing a single-sided document, i.e. pages appear only on the recto side of sheets. When arranged in a double-side spread, nevertheless, this would be the right side. For single sheets it’s the front side. Only these are numbered, of course.

*Temporary content* may appear on verso (= back or left) pages, though. By that, I mean stuff that is only relevant during the *drafting process*, i.e. document option `draft` is set or `final` is not.

In this stage of document preparation, I would like to put *to-do notes* (which may contain graphics and tables) and *full bibliographic entries* for all citations that appear in the current (recto) page onto an adjacent verso page.

All of this is mainly relevant for proof-reading a print-out. It should be possible to switch which verso page is used for the draft-only content, though.
I want it to be on the *following* verso page (accessible by turning the sheet), if I’m checking few single pages.
I want it to be on the *preceding* verso page (accessed by looking left), when checking the whole document, which is probably stapled.

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{fixme}
  \let\todo\fxnote % we don’t need the prefix flexibility from FiXme
  %\fxuselayouts{…}
  \fxsetup{marginclue}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{foo2014,author = {Foo Bar},year = {2014},title = {Baz}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
This is text on a recto page.
\autocite[This citation appears in the document bibliography, 
          but also on a verso page.]{foo2014}
\todo{This to-do note appears on a verso page,
      a marker is put into the margin.}

This is more text on a recto page.
\newpage
This is text on another recto page.
\end{document}
```

The to-do packages `easy-todo` and `todonotes` both provide a command `\listoftodos` to output all notes in a central place, but both only support a single list for all to-dos, not limited to a chapter, section or (as I need) page. The package `FiXme` seems more promising, although its `\listoffixmes` is also global.

Comment: The dimension of `listoffixmes` or `\listoftodos` can be limited very easy. However most of your question irritates me :-) (Sorry).

Comment: Can you make your question a bit more precise? I have just read it twice and still only have a very rough idea of what you want to do. Maybe a mockup graphic might help...